# Isomorphism irreducible components of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a morphism between noetherian schemes of finite type over a field such that $f$ restrict to an isomorphism on every irreducible component of $X$. Under which assumptions is it true that $f$ itself is an isomorphism?

Away from the intersection one can construct an inverse. It is enough to require that the intersection is "nice" enough, e.g. the components intersect tranversally.

Comment: Transversal intersection is not enough. For example, consider $X$ to be two lines defined by $xy=0$ in the plane, and $f:X\to\mathbb{A}^1$ given by $x+y$.

Comment: Nice example. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Closed subschemes are generally not well behaved for gluing -- for example, how do you choose what scheme structures to put on components of $X$? I think the only situation in which there is a truly canonical one is if the irreducible components of $X$ are also open. Another issue you have, is what do you mean by the restriction of $f$ to a component $X_i$ being an isomorphism? What is the target scheme? Presumably the scheme theoretic image of $X_i$ $"f(X_i)"$. Even if $f(X_i)$ is open as a subset (e.g. in this case, take $f injective), it may not be an open subscheme.

Comment: (incidentally, Noetherian follows from finite type over a field.)